# How can I fetch unordered list inside a list from MYSQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, content-management-system

An unordered list is already being fetched from MYSQL database and now I want to fetch the sub list of each heading in a list ending with a drop down.

The hard part is that I want the child-list be fetched from database.

Plus it should be placed with respect to the foreign key assigned.

Menu 1 (id = 1)

Sub Menu 1(sub id = 1)

```
 <ul class="subjects">
 <?php
 //db query
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM  `subjects` ';
 $query .= 'WHERE visible = 1 ';
 $query .= 'ORDER BY position ASC';
 $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 confirm_query($subject_set);
 while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) { ?>
    <li>
        <?php
        echo $subject['menu_name'];

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM  `pages` ';
        $query .= 'WHERE visible = 1 ';
        $query .= 'AND subject_id = ' . $subject['id']. ' ';
        $query .= 'ORDER BY subject_id ASC';
        $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        echo mysqli_error($connection);
        confirm_query($page_set);
        ?>
        <ul class="pages">
            <?php
            while ($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)) {
                ?>
                <li>
                    <?php echo $page['menu_name']; ?>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
            mysqli_free_result($page_set);
            ?>
         </ul>
       </li>
     <?php } ?>
     </ul>
```

Menu 2(id = 2)

Sub Menu 2(sub id = 2)

Please if someone can help.

Comment: Any code ? what have you tried so far ? Please provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems like you only need a simple left join, but your question is not precise.

Comment: What is the schema of the table where you are getting the items? How many menu levels are possible?

Comment: Three tables, Each having maximum of 5 rows.
ID, NAME, VISIBLE, POSITION